# Adding UITableView inside UITableViewCell. TableView height making based on content

Tags: iphone, swift, autolayout, xib

I have created UITableViewCell which contains with following hierarchy

UITableViewCell
------ ContentView
------------ScrollView
------------------TableView

Scrolling on TableView is stopped.

I have taken outlet of height constraint of TableView in custom class in which table's delegate and datasource is implemented.

Up till this point data is visible with one issue. [ Table height is fixed which is set to 50 px via constraint from xib ]

Now inside willDisplay call I am updating height constraint to tableview's content size. But this is not getting updated immediately. Once I scroll the table View it show table with updated height.

Have debugged around constraint's constant which is showing correctly but UI is showing old height though I have called reloadData on tableview. anything missing here...

GitHub Link : https://github.com/sagarmane19/Sample-Apps

Answer (score 4):

1.Create a custom class for inner `tableView` with the following override:

```
class InnerTableView: UITableView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return self.contentSize
    }
}
```

2.Return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` in `heightForRow` method in your view controller:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

3.Make sure you have `top` and `bottom` constraints for cell's inner `tableView`.

Comment: I have tried with this approach. Now able to see couple of more cell which earlier showing only one cell.  This is how it is looking right now : https://sagarm.tinytake.com/sf/MTM3Nzc2NF81MDA3MDg2

Comment: @Sagar... Yes, the point is that you don't specify height constraint for views with dynamic height, but rely on autolayout instead.

Comment: Removed all the height constraint but seems like scrollview's height is not getting updated and table is looking cut in cell.

Comment: i have a problem with nested tableview wrapper is too high and tableview height is calculated wrong on scrolling.